# Android setSubmitButtonEnabled not working

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm using SearchView to filter my ListView data. I managed to implement it, but I can't get this code to work.

```
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
```

This is my full code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_group_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint_type_something));
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

    int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
    if (searchPlate != null) {
        int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView searchText = (TextView) searchPlate.findViewById(searchTextId);
        if (searchText != null) {
            searchText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
    }

    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}
```

Image:
[image: See image]

If anyone have a clue in How to I hide the submit button beside searchview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line of code from your code.

```
//remove this line 
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```